# How to call functions (in both directions) across processes in Python using MultiProcessing?

Tags: python, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing, ipc

I have two separate python processes, one is not spawned by the other. The server listens on localhost:50000 as such:

```
from multiprocessing.managers import BaseManager

def my_func(arg=None): print(arg)

class FuncManager(BaseManager): pass

FuncManager.register('get_func', callable=lambda:my_func)
m = FuncManager(address=('', 50000), authkey=b'abracadabra')

s = m.get_server()
s.serve_forever()
```

```
from multiprocessing.managers import BaseManager

class FuncManager(BaseManager): pass
FuncManager.register('get_func')
m = FuncManager(address=('', 50000), authkey=b'abracadabra')
m.connect()
func = m.get_func()
func("foo")
```

But it throws an exception, that func isn't callable, even though it reports its type as a function. Is there a way in Python for two separate processes to be able to pass and trigger callbacks from one another (ideally with arguments and return values)? If not, what is the simplest additional package or workaround needed to achieve this?

I did manage to be able to call functions defined in another process while passing arguments and getting return values, but the functions have to be defined in a class, and it works only from client calling the server. I can't get it to work the other way around or use arbitrary functions (such as passing them as arguments). Having to predefine them in the class seems too much of a constraint, because I don't see how then several clients can connect using the same class/socket-address and still be able to call the server such that the server knows which client is calling, and such that the server can call any client specifically at any moment without requiring being called by the client first.

I wouldn't mind using IPC/RPC such that clients connect to a socket, and then functions are called through the socket. But each side needs to know (through exceptions/events not through polling of socket), if/when the other process has terminated, and be able to dynamically un-/register one or more callbacks with the other side in a simple pythonic way. Is there a simple/reliable package in python to do this?

Comment: Can you edit the question including the full exception and its traceback?

Comment: you can use [dill](https://pypi.org/project/dill/) to send functions across the network, but i need to quote it on that `dill is quite flexible, and allows arbitrary user defined classes and functions to be serialized. Thus dill is not intended to be secure against erroneously or maliciously constructed data. It is left to the user to decide whether the data they unpickle is from a trustworthy source.`

Comment: You are not attempting to "call functions in both directions" based on the code you have created. See my answer posted below. What you need to be doing is to wrap what is currently function `my_func` in a class instance a proxy to which is returned to the client. Then when you call `func('foo')` the actual execution is taking place in the manager's process (started by the server).

Comment: I discovered rpyc... but it has it's own set of problems... such as not working as documented, and the features I need not being documented. So currently it only seems useful if you want to call builtins or trigger callbacks using builtins.